# lodash to find common values from array of objects

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, lodash

Find common values from Array of Objects and Transom them

tried using lodash groupBy

```
var data =[
  {
    "dc": 1,
    "effDate": "1/2/2019",
    "expDate": "1/2/2019",
    "rate": 1,
    "minCharge": 2
  },
  {
    "dc": 1,
    "effDate": "1/2/2019",
    "expDate": "1/2/2019",
    "rate": 2,
    "minCharge": 6
  },
  {
    "dc": 1,
    "effDate": "1/2/2019",
    "expDate": "1/2/2019",
    "rate": 4,
    "minCharge": 7
  }
]

var expectedResult=[
  {
    "dc": 1,
    "effDate": "1/2/2019",
    "expDate": "1/2/2019",
    "rateCharge": [
      {
        "rate": 1,
        "minCharge": 2
      },
      {
        "rate": 2,
        "minCharge": 6
      },
      {
        "rate": 4,
        "minCharge": 7
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

in data dc,effDate,expDate are same, so i need to keep common things as flat structure and move repeating items into rateCharge.

```
var expectedResult=uniqBy(data,(val1.rate,val2.rate) => {
  val1.rate!=val2.rate;    
});
```

I have tried using lodash uniqBy property but i am not getting expected result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to group the items by the `effDate`, and then map the groups to the required form using `_.pick()` / `_.omit()` , `_.map()`, and using `_.uniqBy()` with the `rate` as the unique identifier.

[Typescript example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/lodash-error-mteye2?file=index.ts) (open the browsers console)

```js
const { flow, partialRight: pr, groupBy, map, head, pick, omit, uniqBy } = _

const EFF_DATA = 'effDate'
const baseProps = ['dc', EFF_DATA, 'expDate']

const fn = flow(
  pr(groupBy, EFF_DATA),
  pr(map, g => ({
    ...pick(head(g), baseProps),
    rateCharge: uniqBy(map(g, pr(omit, baseProps)), 'rate')
  }))
)

const data = [{"dc":1,"effDate":"1/2/2019","expDate":"1/2/2019","rate":1,"minCharge":2},{"dc":1,"effDate":"1/2/2019","expDate":"1/2/2019","rate":2,"minCharge":6},{"dc":1,"effDate":"1/2/2019","expDate":"1/2/2019","rate":4,"minCharge":7}]

const result = fn(data)

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

If you already import the entire lodash packages, you can use chaining:

```js
const { flow, partialRight: pr, groupBy, map, head, pick, omit, uniqBy } = _

const EFF_DATA = 'effDate'
const baseProps = ['dc', EFF_DATA, 'expDate']

const data = [{"dc":1,"effDate":"1/2/2019","expDate":"1/2/2019","rate":1,"minCharge":2},{"dc":1,"effDate":"1/2/2019","expDate":"1/2/2019","rate":2,"minCharge":6},{"dc":1,"effDate":"1/2/2019","expDate":"1/2/2019","rate":4,"minCharge":7}]

const result = _(data)
  .groupBy(EFF_DATA)
  .map(g => ({
    ...pick(head(g), baseProps),
    rateCharge: uniqBy(map(g, pr(omit, baseProps)), 'rate')  
  }));

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

And the lodash/fp version:

```js
const { flow, groupBy, map, head, pick, omit, uniqBy, assoc } = _;

const EFF_DATA = 'effDate'
const baseProps = ['dc', EFF_DATA, 'expDate'];

const fn = flow(
  groupBy(EFF_DATA),
  map(g => assoc(
    'rateCharge',
    flow(map(omit(baseProps)), uniqBy('rate'))(g),
    pick(baseProps, head(g))
  ))
)

const data = [{"dc":1,"effDate":"1/2/2019","expDate":"1/2/2019","rate":1,"minCharge":2},{"dc":1,"effDate":"1/2/2019","expDate":"1/2/2019","rate":2,"minCharge":6},{"dc":1,"effDate":"1/2/2019","expDate":"1/2/2019","rate":4,"minCharge":7}]

const result = fn(data)

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/g/lodash@4(lodash.min.js+lodash.fp.min.js)'></script>
```

Comment: `lodash/fp` exists so you don't have to `pr` everything

Comment: Unfortunately, most users don't use lodash/fp yet. I usually add a lodash/fp solution as well, which I'll do soon.

Comment: Nice update. Maybe mention how this works because you're stringing all of the values together with `-` to make a grouping key. And maybe mention how using `-` will cause an odd behaviour if the values may possibly contain `-`. Maybe too much to mention how a custom data type could support _real_ compound data equality :D

Comment: What is underscore means? How can i use the same using lodash with angular(typescript)? Any difference in syntax? Please help

Comment: Instead of destructuring the underscore, in angular you will import the various functions from lodash (or lodash/fp). That's the main difference in syntax.

Comment: @OriDrori: i am not able to regenerate it in typescript way getting some syntax errors. Could you please check url
https://stackblitz.com/edit/lodash-to73n4?file=index.ts

Comment: I've updated the code to fit your case, and added a typescript example.

Comment: @OriDrori: i am getting the expected output, but the code is difficult to understand. Why u have declared fn as a constant. as i am a beginner i have difficulties to understand the code. is it possible to convert it as a function

Comment: Lodash's flow returns a function, so I've assigned that to a constant. I've added another solution using lodash chaining, without `flow()` or functions.

Comment: but typescript wont allow _(data).groupBy syntax can u please help

Comment: I already did. Use the one with the flow and the type at the link.

Comment: import _ from 'lodash' is not allowed in my coding standard, any way to avoid this by importing the items we need?

Comment: You can use `import flow from 'lodash/flow'`; |import map from 'lodash/map'`; etc...

Comment: how can i replace  "_(data)"  with individual imports?

Comment: You can't. That's why I use flow.